# Accessing Filesystemwatcher value in second window of WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a filesystemwatcher to monitor a folder for new files being created. This runs on a function in my mainwindow.xaml. I want to access the file name in my second window(viewer.xaml). Can you advice me on how I can do that? From below, I want to access string filepath in my second window.

```
public void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        //folder name
        string filePath = e.FullPath;
    }
```

Comment: If your Window (class) exposes a public property, say, `public string GiveMeTheFileName()`, the property setter can do something with this information. It could also be a public method that accepts a string parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much Jim. I was considering doing it this way, but wondered if there is another way through the WPF access.

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this. Common interfaces, dependency injection, blah blah. Start with something and build on it.